# RoR 3.0.7 UTF-8 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8

RoR keeps trowing this error:

incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
Extracted source (around line #631):

```
628:     </table>
629:     </td>
630:     <td width="828" valign="top">
631:       <%=  yield %>
632:       <br />
633:     </td>
634:   </tr>
```

How can `<%= yield %>` be causing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Can you add the whole error backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your file:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

and probably make sure that this is in your config/application.rb:

```
module Foo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
  end
end
```

Comment: of which file? the .html.erb?

Comment: Hmm, my only other suggestion would be to delete the `yield` line and re-type it, as maybe an invalid character somehow snuck into that line.

Comment: Also, make sure your editor is actually saving the file in utf-8 encoding

Comment: Nothing... I think I need to use mysql2 instead of the mysql gem... However I'm developing on Windows and mysql2 has no support for win. I think there's a way around to install it... ?? (hope so)

Comment: Ah too bad. Maybe you should upgrade to Linux? ;) Good luck.